# How do you set an icon for Metamask "DApp Connect" popup prompt?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps

For example, here, how would someone get a logo to appear instead of the default "A" logo?

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metamask uses the favicon for your site.

See here for how to set one up:
https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Comment: Are you sure? I have a favicon set up and Metamask isn't getting it. Is there some piece of documentation that you are aware of that talks about this?

Comment: https://www.arbol.app/favicon.ico

Comment: I didn't get it from the docs, I just inspected the image it uses on my site which worked without any effort on my part and confirmed that it was the favicon image.
https://realitio.github.io/

Try specifying it in the HTML rather than just relying on it being in the directory root - mine is: 
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='assets/image/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' />

Comment: It seems hardcoded to `<your-domain>/favicon.png`; you can tell this stuff is bleeding edge when you can't customize something so trivial...